# Doctrine Query Builder mysql Functions

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

im atempting to create one of my old mysql queries in Doctrine Query Builder however im getting back an error **Error: Expected known function, got 'SEC_TO_TIME'**

So im guessing that doctrine doesnt like the mysql function **SEC_TO_TIME** however it does seem to like **AVG**, **COUNT** and such. Is there any way apart form using the Doctrine_RawSQL class of getting the query builder to run the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those `AVG` and `Count` are DQL aggregate functions, they have nothing to do with SQL. So there is no way to call UDF's from DQL, except for RawSQL

But, if you are using doctrine2, you might want to have a look at [Adding your own functions to the DQL language](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#registering-your-own-dql-functions) and [Extending DQL in Doctrine 2: User-Defined Functions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html).

Comment: hello not a single link is working. kindly update above links.

Comment: @AmitJoshi Hi! I've left Doctrine and PHP space a long time ago, so I'm afraid I have no idea where they are now. Feel free to edit the answer if you find where they were moved.

Answer (score 3):

i know this question is very old, but i am answering this question for others who having same error.
you just need to add below code in form of file Named "SecToTime.php" as below path.

> YourProjectName\libraries\Doctrine\DoctrineExtensions\Query\MySql\SecToTime.php

And put below code in above file Named "SecToTime.php".

```
<?php

namespace DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class SecToTime extends FunctionNode {

    public $time;

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker) {
        return 'SEC_TO_TIME(' . $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticPrimary($this->time) . ')';
    }

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser) {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->time = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

}
```

you need to add above file name in your doctrine.php file for using it further. i hope you know how to add it.

If you having any query, feel free to ask.